# Javascript + Django, simple calculation not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, jinja2

I need to make a simple division between two numbers for more than 100 items in a list of variables,

Inside the loop the HTML looks something like:

```
<input id="box1{{ item.0 }}" type="text" onkeyup="calculate()" />
<input id="box2{{ item.0 }}" type="text" onkeyup="calculate()" value="{{ item.7 }}"/>
<input id="result{{ item.0 }}" />
```

And my script

```
function calculate(){
    console.log(1);
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1{{ item.0 }}').value;
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2{{ item.0 }}').defaultValue;
    var result = document.getElementById('result{{ item.0 }}');
    var myResult = myBox1 / myBox2;
    result.value = myResult;}
```

For some reason I can't get this to work inside the loop, the script is inside the loop for each item in my list, maybe it is because JS can't capture the jinja variable {{ item }} ?

Comment: What happens when you do console.log(''{{item}}")?

Comment: Sorry but i'm kinda new to JS, if I change console.log(1) to console.log("{{item}}"), in the source code of the live page shows the correct information, 

                function calculate(){
                      console.log("001");

Comment: See what your console shows you for the command: console.log(myBox1); ? Put the command after the line: var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1{{ item.0 }}').value;

Comment: So you create a function called `calculate()` for each `item` in the loop? That would leave you with just _one_ function for the last `item` called by all `<input>` fields on key release.

Comment: BlackJack I think I understand what you are saying, but how can I fix this ?

Comment: Put the necessary information as argument(s) into the call, or even better don't use the `onkeyup` attribute but code to bind the callback(s) to the input elements.

Answer (score -1):

So... It works now, I know that this is not the best solution but here it is:

```
        <input id="box1{{ item.0 }}" type="text" onkeyup="calculate{{item.0}}()" />
        <input id="box2{{ item.0 }}" type="text" onkeyup="calculate{{item.0}}()" value="{{ item.7 }}"/>
        <input id="result{{ item.0 }}" />

        <script>
        function calculate{{coin.0}}(){
        console.log("{{ item.0 }}");
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1{{ item.0 }}').value;
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2{{ item.0 }}').defaultValue;
        var result = document.getElementById('result{{ item.0 }}');
        var myResult = myBox1 / myBox2;
        result.value = myResult;}
        </script>
```

I changed **function** **calculate()** to **function calculate{{item.0}}()**